# Update DetailViewController with Selected PFUser content from UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, segue

I'm building an social network aplication and at the moment I want to create a segue between HomeViewController and OtherUserViewController when the PFUser.CurrentUser() selects another user's Cell from UICollectionView. The segue is working perfectly, but the otherUserName Label is not updating the name of the selected PFUser.

I've generated a list of all the users and put each of them in their own Cell.

```
var userListData = [String]()
var userListUserNames = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var userCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    userCollectionView.delegate = self
    userCollectionView.dataSource = self
    loadData()
}
func loadData (){
    var userListQuery = PFUser.query()
    userListQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    if let user = object as? PFUser {

                        if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                            self.userListData.append(user.objectId!)
                            self.userListUserNames.append(user.username!)
                            self.userCollectionView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

After that I created the cells.

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userListData.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("homeCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    var names = self.userListUserNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.profileNameButtonOutlet.setTitle(names.lowercaseString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    return cell
}
```

Then i created a prepareForSegue method and the didDeselectItemAtIndexPath for the cell.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var currentOtherUser: PFObject?
    if let object = sender as? PFObject {

        currentOtherUser = sender as? PFObject
    } else {
        println("there is no currentOtherUser")
    }
    var otherUserScene = segue.destinationViewController as! OtherUserViewController
    otherUserScene.currentOtherUser = (currentOtherUser)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let currentOtherUser = userListUserNames[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("homeToOtherUser", sender: currentOtherUser)
}
```

In my detail controller I've set up the retrieval of information.

```
class OtherUserViewController: UIViewController {

var currentOtherUser : PFObject?

@IBOutlet weak var otherUserName: UILabel!

var otherUser: PFUser?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let object = currentOtherUser {
        if let value = object["username"] as? String {

            otherUserName.text = value

        }
    } else {
        println("no name to display")
    }
}
}
```

The return on prepareForSegue is always nil, so is the ViewDidLoad for OtherUserViewController.

What am I doing wrong and how could I set up the segue correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you are doing is logically fine and theres no problem with segues. The problem however are:

```
  var userListUserNames = [String]()   // This is not [PFOBject]
```

But on the prepare for segue you are checking for:

```
 if let object = sender as? PFObject {
    //which will never be called because sender is of type <String>
    currentOtherUser = sender as? PFObject
} else {
    println("there is no currentOtherUser")  //this is what is being displayed right now
}
```

That is because of:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
let currentOtherUser = userListUserNames[indexPath.row]  //This is String
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("homeToOtherUser", sender: currentOtherUser)
```

}

Thats the problem.

The solution would be either having type to String if you do that you get the name but you might lose other associated properties of the otherUser which might be required later on. If thats the case i would suggest storing the entire PFObject in the array and using that, that way you don't have to call Parse time and again but you use a bit of memory.

But there is also a danger lurking in your code. Don't call UI update from a separate thread.  If I'm correct the parse block is being executed from a separate thread and it is advisable to post UI update on main thread like so:

```
userListQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil && objects != nil{
            for object in objects! {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                        self.userListData.append(user.objectId!)
                        self.userListUserNames.append(user.username!)

                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                             self.userCollectionView.reloadData()
                       })

                    }
                }
            }
    }
})
```

Let me know if that helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, it did help! I changed the PFObject in the if let statement like so
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var currentObject : String?
        if let current = sender as? String {
        currentObject = sender as? String
        }
        var secVS: OtherUserViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! OtherUserViewController
        secVS.currentOtherUser = (currentObject)!
    }
everything works fine now. Your advice is better, i'll store all my objects in an array and call each user when needed.